# USB Hub suitable for powering a RPi 3 b+ and multiple usb sticks?

Tags: usb, power

I was wondering if it was possible to power a raspberry pi 3 b+ and a dozen usb 3.0 sticks, or if not, what would be the best recommended way to go about this, ideally i'm looking for an off the shelf solution as i don't want to cause a fire with making a diy solution.

Comment: You may be able to power them, but you may run into problems accessing them all. AFAIK there's a limit to the number of USB memory devices that can be accessed at the same time (somewhere around 6 to 8, IIRC)

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic , Asking for specific purchasing recommendations:

Answer (score 2):

This question is partly speculative, too vague and unanswerable.

The one part which can be answered you **CAN NOT** power a Pi from a hub.
There are some non-compliant hubs which will provide more than 500mA but being non-compliant they are usually ill defined and thus unknown.

The Pi requires a minimum of 1A - preferably 2.5A from a proper power supply.

Comment: You can power any RPi1, zero or original B+ or A+ from a 500mA USB as long as the RPi doesn't have any USB devices plugged in. Any RPi from the 2B upwards won't run reliably from 500mA.

Comment: @Dougie this may be true - if doubtful, but is totally irrelevant as the OP has a pi 3 b+. Not to mention a compliant hub will only supply 150mA unless a higher current is negotiated - which the Pi **can't** do because the power port has no data channel.

Comment: i guess my best option is to get another two raspberry pi's so i can power all dozen usb sticks?

Comment: @HaveaLaugh, no your best option is not to get more Raspberries (unless there is a need for that not yet covered in your question) but get two powered seven/eight-port hubs, connect both directly to the Pi (do not chain them) (compare to 12 port hubs if you like, I found those to be prohibitively expensive). Chances are that you can power both hubs from the same supply depending on the flash drives connected, but that would require to make your own cable (DIY involved).

Answer (score -1):

Here is one possibility how to power RPi from USB hub.

https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/5-Port-USB-2-0-Hub-Power-Supply-Module-for-Raspberry-Pi-3-2-Model-B/1534002_32791917109.html

Also check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9D8N3BwYL4w

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer just with links; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes.